# SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c while establishing a connection with integrated security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I get the following error while trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 using JDBC connection.

```
 Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 2.
 Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c while establishing 
             a connection with integrated security; the connection has been 
             closed. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
 Logon       Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted 
             SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
```

MY connection URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true
```

Comment: I have the same problem using the jtds jdbc driver (from one windows machine to another windows machine both on the same domain).  I have not yet found a solution.  The best advice I've heard so far is "something is wrong with AD".

Comment: This error happens 100% of the time if you try to log in the SQL Server with integrated security but your current security context is from another domain (not trusted) or logged locally on the client machine.

Answer (score 18):

The key to this issue, for me at least, is the fact that the connection to SQL Server is being made over the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). I had the same symptoms, and found the answer in [this blog post](http://www.bhcblog.com/2009/10/08/fix-for-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection/).

To summarise: there is a loopback check taking place which causes trusted connections via the loopback adapter to fail. This check can be removed by adding a registry entry as follows:

1. Edit the registry using regedit.  (start –> run … Regedit )
2. Browse to :  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
3. Add a DWORD value called “DisableLoopbackCheck”
4. Set this value to 1

I rebooted after making this change, just to be sure, but you may find that this is not necessary. After this registry change was effected, I could make trusted connections via the loopback adapter.

Kudos to the [Blackhawk Consulting Blog](http://www.bhcblog.com/) for pointing me in the right direction on this issue.

Comment: I have the same error over the network. So it is not necessarilly due to using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I have been trying to fix this for over a month now with out success.  Stumbled on this SO post and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. BTW, the first link no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem, and the cause was simple: my domain user's password had expired, so the credentials had been revoked.

As it happened, I had also left SQL Management Studio open so it generated errors like these every 2-3 minutes until I changed my domain password.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact message with this 0x8009030c code.

In my case, the user didn't have access to the sql computer from the network and I had a failure audit message indicating that (I think the same message also happens in other cases).

Go to: Local Security Policy -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Access this computer from the network -> add the user

It fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft's err.exe

```
C:\>err 0x8009030c
# for hex 0x8009030c / decimal -2146893044 :
  SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED                                            winerror.h
# The logon attempt failed
# 1 matches found for "0x8009030c"
```

A DC will deny a login for many different reasons, including intermittent connectivity failures to a DC.

Comment: is this an answer? I cannot see any solution to the OP problem

Answer (score 0):

Another cause can be if the account is locked out. We had this due to a rogue service running every half hour with the wrong password. The account was a service account and set to unlock itself after a few minutes where this occurred so it was quite difficult to track down.