# SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c when connecting to localhost, but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using JDBC to connect to SQL Server 2005 locally using integrated security. It is failing with:

```
Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 2.

Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.

Logon       Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
```

But I am able to connect successfully using `127.0.0.1`. The connection is failing only when I give `localhost`.

MY Connection URL is

```
jdbc:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true
```

Comment: What happens if you don't used integrated security and login with a user id and passowrd? Does it still give you some error?

Comment: it works but i need to work with the integrated security only

Comment: I believe that this is a [duplicate of this question][1], and a useful answers can be found there.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538027/sspi-handshake-failed-with-error-code-0x8009030c-while-establishing-a-connection