# SQL login failed because due to untrusted domain

Tags: .net, sql-server, active-directory

- I have a VM that houses both the SQL server and the IIS server.
- My IIS server has an application pool that run a .NET web application.
- This application pool identity is domain\account1
- My application web.config connection string has "Trusted_Connection=True" and Data
  Source=NAME\INSTANCE01
- My SQL server has "SQL Server and Window Authetnication mode" enabled. The account domain\account1 is added to the database security login.
- I can RDP into this VM using  domain\account1 and I can connect to the Database via SMS using
  Window Authentication and connecting to NAME\INSTANCE01
- I verify that only have one domain on our AD and DC.

However, when I tried to log in my web application, the .NET error trace shows it fails at the login.
Upon looking at the Database's log I see the error below.  The error seems to indicate the Identity user (domain\account1) I'm using in my .NET application cannot log into the database due to this error.

[image]

This has been baffling because I researched around and found this error only occur if you connect from an outside domain but I don't know why it shows this in my case.

I tried and look into my AD but it looks like it is up because if it isn't I would not have been able to RDP into the VM using domain\account1 in the first place.

Any guidance that help me narrow down the cause are much welcomed.

Comment: The message makes it seem like something is trying to log in with a user name like `UnknownDomain\someUser`, but that's never *really* the case.  The `SSPI handshake failure` has a lot of root causes. You'll have to dig through some stuff. See an MS blog entry [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/docast/common-sspi-handshake-failed-errors-and-troubleshooting).If your SQL instance is running as a domain account, you may be missing an SPN. Get a DBA to check the `auth_scheme` column on `sys.dm_exec_connections`. If you see any saying "kerberos", you're fine on that one.

Comment: thank you @allmhuran I ran your query and I see all of the auth_scheme are "NTLM".  I also verified that our SQL service is running via domain account as well.  The domain name is the same.

Comment: OK, since SQL is runing as a regular domain account, it will not be able to register its own SPN on startup. A domain administrator will need to register an SPN on its behalf. Wait, I'll post an answer.. I can't fit this here.

Comment: thanks, i have access to the Active Directory so I can setup any user to create SPN i think, I'll wait for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on our conversation, one common cause that might apply is that the SQL Server does not have a service principal name registered. This is something it needs in order for kerberos to work.

To do this, you use the [`setspn`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/717.service-principal-names-spn-setspn-syntax.aspx) utility.

There's a lot in the document, here are the basics. A service principal name applies to some particular service (eg, sql server), on some particular machine and port, to some particular domain account. Let's pretend your server machine name is MyServer, and the account running SQL Server instance is MyDomain\SQLAccount, and it's a default instance (running on port 1433. If it's a named instance, find the port via sql configuration manager or by looking at the start of the sql log and subtitute it below)

To see a list of SPN's assigned to the account, you would use

```
setspn -l MyDomain\SQLAccount
```

To register a SPN for the SQL Server service, it's best to register for the netbios name and the fully qualified name:

```
setspn -a MSSQLSvc/MyServer:1433 MyDomain\SQLAccount
setspn -a MSSQLSvc/MyServer.mydomain.com:1433 MyDomain\SQLAccount
```

Now, if you have several domain controllers, the SPN may take a while to replicate around the domain. So you have to wait "long enough" to see this take effect. 15 minutes is common, 30 is definitely safe. So after running this, wait a while, then make a *new* connection to SQL server (using, eg, SSMS and windows auth) and `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid` again. If you see "kerberos", it worked. You can also run `klist purge` from command line to purge your tickets, but that's not usually necessary, and it won't help if the ticket hasn't replicated yet.

This isn't the only possible reason why you might get SSPI problems - see that MS blog for more. But it is a really common one.

EDIT:

Kerberos problems *usually* only happen when you have a "double hop" of credentials. For example, from a user's machine, to a web server, then from the web server to a SQL Server. That doesn't apply in your specific case. But I would still try this SPN setup anyway, because it's just such a common source of SSPI errors.

Comment: Using your name scheme, I ran the setspn -l <mydomain.com\username> of the user running my SQL service and I see there are two entries : MSSQLSvc/MyServer.mycomain.com:50174 and MSSQLSvc/MyServer.mycomain.com:INSTANCE01  .  So that means the SQL service user already have its SPN entries.

Comment: Yep, it does. That's a bummer, this is usually a quick fix to most SSPI related issues. The fact that IIS and SQL are on the same machine means kerberos isn't actulaly *necessary* for handling double hops, but it seemed worth a shot.... OK, so it's "down the rabbit hole" time now I'm afraid. Often it's a clock discrepancy issue, but again.. if the IIS service and SQL are on the same machine, it can't be that. But it might cause the loopback problem, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538027/sspi-handshake-failed-with-error-code-0x8009030c-while-establishing-a-connection).

Comment: Unfortunately, these are the only three issues that I know "off the top of my head" so to speak, that should cover almost all cases of SSPI problems - ie, SPN's, clock discrepancy, and loopback. If it's none of those three I can be of no better help that google. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is... odd... though, that you're getting an NTLM connection, not a kerberos connection, if SQL is configured with its SPN. Unless you're running SSMS *on* the server as well?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I ran my script inside SSMS.  I closed it out after seeing your message and use SQLCMD instead.  Now I am seeing one KERBEROS.  However, my problem of the web access still there :( , I'll keep digging to see what I can figure out.  Thanks @allmhuran .  By the way, is it a problem if my AD server and my SQL server time are off by 10 seconds? because that is what I'm seeing.

Comment: Yes, actually, that may well be a problem. Off the top of my head I don't know what amount of "grace" is built into the timing of a keberos ticket, but yes, if the domain controller is not synched with the SQL server, that could *definitely* be causing this.
Edit: Kerberos grace is, apparently, "typically" 5 minutes. So it's probably not this.

Comment: Actually - since you did in fact get a kerberos ticket using sqlcmd, and since there's no third machine involved (because iis and sql are colocated) it can't be this.  If it were me, my next check would be [the loopback solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538027/sspi-handshake-failed-with-error-code-0x8009030c-while-establishing-a-connection). Then the solution in [the MS blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/docast/common-sspi-handshake-failed-errors-and-troubleshooting), and then... your guess is as good as mine